# Why is Silver-108 unstable?

Tags: nuclear-physics, stability, binding-energy, elements, isotopes

Why is Silver-108 unstable if silver-107 and silver-109 are stable?
I found it on crash course but no answer was given.

Comment: The short and unhelpful answer is *"Given [the decay modes](http://ie.lbl.gov/toi/nuclide.asp?iZA=470108) it is simply that Palladium-108 and Cadmium-108 are both sufficiently lower energy states than the silver isotope."* If I was trying to track this down, I'd note that Ag-108 is a odd-odd nucleus, so it pays a penalty in pairing energy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hand-waving answer is nuclear pairing energy. Protons and neutrons prefer to move in pairs in the nucleus, and they prefer to pair like-to-like rather than one to another.  This means that, for the most part, nuclei with odd proton number and odd neutron number ("odd-odd nuclei") are less tightly bound than "even-even nuclei," and the odd-odd nuclei tend to turn into even-even nuclei by a weak decay.

In fact, there are only eight naturally-occurring odd-odd isotopes: four light isotopes which are actually stable (deuterium, lithium-6, boron-10, and nitrogen-14) and four with lifetimes comparable to the age of the earth (potassium-40, vanadium-50, lanthanum-158, and lutetium-176). The pattern on the [chart of nuclides](http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/chart/) is quite striking: for instance, tin ($Z=50$) has ten stable isotopes, while its odd-$Z$ neighbors indium and antimony have only two each, both with even neutron numbers.