# Why do Xe-135 and Zr-88 have a surprisingly large thermal neutron capture cross-section?

Tags: experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, neutrons, nuclear-engineering

Why do Xe-135 and  Zr-88 have surprisingly large thermal neutron capture cross-sections?

> The probability that a nucleus will absorb a neutron—the neutron capture cross-section—is important to many areas of nuclear science, including stellar nucleosynthesis, reactor performance, nuclear medicine, and defense applications. Although neutron capture cross-sections have been measured for most stable nuclei, fewer results exist for radioactive isotopes, and statistical-model predictions typically have large uncertainties. There is almost no nuclear data for neutron-induced reactions of the radioactive nucleus $^{88}Zr$, despite its importance as a diagnostic for nuclear security.
> Here, by exposing $^{88}Zr$ to the intense neutron flux of a nuclear reactor, we determine that $^{88}Zr$ has a thermal neutron capture cross-section of $861,000 \pm 69,000$ barns ($1\sigma$ uncertainty), which is five orders of magnitude larger than the theoretically predicted value of $10$ barns. This is the second-largest thermal neutron capture cross-section ever measured and no other cross-section of comparable size has been discovered in the past 70 years. The only other nuclei known to have values greater than $10^5$ barns are $^{135}Xe$ ($2.6 \times 10^6$ barns), a fission product that was first discovered as a poison in early reactors, and $^{157}Gd$ ($2.5 × 10^5$ barns).

My question is why do these isotopes have such a large thermal neutron capture cross-section? What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Please include the source of that quote in your question.

Comment: Presumeably https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-018-0838-z#:~:text=Here%2C%20by%20exposing%2088Zr,value%20of%2010%20barns2. ?

Comment: As the paper in question says, "Because there are so few cross-sections of this magnitude known,
consensus has not been reached in establishing an explanation that
accounts for their behaviour" - so asking the internet why seems a bit odd if the experts writing the paper don't know.

Comment: Hello Jon, Yeah i have read that paper. I was confused that they didnt explain why it happens.

Comment: Similar question as: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/543429/why-does-gadolinium-have-the-highest-neutron-cross-section?rq=1

Comment: @NuclearFission so basically the answer is "we don't know"... Quite surprising, since Xe135 is one of the most important isotopes in nuclear engineering.